# Norm clipping technique in TFF

Tags: tensorflow-federated, federated-learning

I'm training a DP federated learning model using the "DP-FedAvg" algorithm, which is based on below paper:

[Learning Differentially Private Recurrent Language Models](https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.06963)

The paper proposes two norm clipping techniques "flat clipping" and "per-layer clipping", then performs the experiments using "per-layer clipping".

In case of TFF, when attaching a DP-query and an aggregation process to the federated model, which clipping technique is implemented by default? Is there a way to specify the clipping technique used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get a basic recommended setup by using [`tff.learning.dp_aggregator`](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/learning/dp_aggregator), and use it as

```
iterative_process = tff.learning.build_federated_averaging_process(
    ...,
    model_update_aggregation_factory=tff.learning.dp_aggregator(...))
```

For guidance of how to use it with in learning algorithms in general, see tutorial: [Tuning recommended aggregations for learning](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/tutorials/tuning_recommended_aggregators).

The default clipping method used corresponds to "flat clipping", as termed in the paper you link to. However, the clipping norm is not fixed, but automatically adapted based on values seen in previous rounds of training. For details, see documentation and the paper [Differentially Private Learning with Adaptive Clipping](https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.03871).

If you want to use a fixed clipping norm `my_clip_norm`, you can look at the implementation and see what components can be modified. I believe you should be able to simply use:

`tff.aggregators.DifferentiallyPrivateFactory.gaussian_fixed(..., clip=my_clip_norm)`

If you wanted to use some form of per-layer clipping, you would need to write your own aggregator. Implementation of `tff.aggregators.DifferentiallyPrivateFactory` could be a good start, and see also tutorial [Implementing Custom Aggregations](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/tutorials/custom_aggregators).

Comment: For per-layer clipping, you can construct a tensorflow_privacy `nested_query` and pass it to the `DifferentiallyPrivateFactory` initializer.

That said, my personal experience with per-layer clipping is that it does not perform as well. For a given level of noise, which implies a given total norm bound, per-layer clipping clips more aggressively, causing more bias.

For example, with two vectors and norm bound 1, it's better to clip the joint norm to 1 than to clip each vector to 1/sqrt(2). If the norms are (.8, .4) joint clipping wouldn't clip at all. It's only worse with more vectors.

Comment: @GalenAndrew, Thanks for the follow up, regarding ```adaptive clipping``` strategy, is there any empirically recommended values to start experimenting with for the parameters ```initial_l2_norm_clip``` , ```target_unclipped_quantile``` ,  ```clipped_count_budget_allocation``` and ```adaptive_clip_learning_rate```  for ```EMNIST``` dataset ?

Comment: Yes, the default values you get from using [`tff.learning.dp_aggregator`](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/learning/dp_aggregator) are the ones justified by [Thakkar et al., 2020](https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.03871).

Comment: How can I extract the value of clip norm from each iteration in tff.learning.model_update_aggregator.dp_aggregator?